# В окне создания синонима не переведены строки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, синонимы-меток

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Create a tag synonym.
2. All new attempts to use this tag will be automatically remapped to the target tag.
3. If you would like to clean up the history, be sure to also merge these two tags.

Comment: А мы ведь пишем на мету только когда строки нет в транзифексе?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я больше не занимаюсь переводами. Поэтому просто уведомил сообщество, что есть такая проблема.

Comment: Не понял, правда, как вызвать это окно. Может быть ромбовидная особенность?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ там синяя кнопка у меня сверху "Создать синоним".

Comment: У меня нетути https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Ofg.png

Comment: @αλεχολυτ странно. Синонимы же не только модеры могут предлагать.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica для создания синонима надо рейтинг по метке 5+ иметь. Видимо, с этим связано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/string/13014
2. https://ru.traducir.win/string/13008
3. https://ru.traducir.win/string/13011